# Send parameter to JS function with input form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have this js function

```
function showThisTag(tag) {
$('#content .blog').not("."+tag).hide();
}
```

how can i send the "tag" parameter from a form?
something like

```
<form name="input" onSubmit="showThisTag(this)">
<input type="text" >
<input type="submit" value="sendit">
</form>
```

thanks!

Comment: Please! The OP is new here; don't vote a new member's question down if you don't have time to explain why!

Comment: What do you mean by tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how you can do it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(txt) {
        alert(txt)
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="arg"/>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfunction(document.getElementById('arg').value)"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks ! but i want to write it on the input form while browsing the page!

Comment: yes, thanks ! this works :-D, also works with just "myfunction(arg.value)"

Comment: @CristianBenítez If it worked don't forget to accept the answer, so people know that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value you want to send in quotes:

```
<form name="input" onSubmit="showThisTag('classToShow')">
```

If you want get the class from the input field, give it a class so you can access it and get its value:

```js
function showThisTag(form) {
  var tag = $(form).find(".tagclass").val();
  $('#content .blog').not("."+tag).hide();
  $("#content .blog."+tag).show();
  return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="input" onSubmit="return showThisTag(this)">
<input type="text" class="tagclass">
<input type="submit" value="sendit">
</form>

<div id="content">
  <div class="blog one">
    Blog post one
  </div>
  <div class="blog two">
    Blog post two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nono, i want to write browsing the page, on the input form and that become the parameter (i dont speak too much english!)